# Data type convert using Derived Column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I used derive column to convert date from csv to DB type but I got this error message
[image]

This is the date type on csv.
[image]

This is the format
[image]

This is the table on db
[image]

I have tried to use Derived Column with two different expressions. This first:
[image]
and this is the second

```cs
(DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET,7)(SUBSTRING(Horodatage,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Horodatage,6,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Horodatage,9,2) + " " + SUBSTRING(Horodatage,12,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(Horodatage,15,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(Horodatage,18,2))
```

None of them have worked for me, I always get this error message.
[image]

I wanted to fill the temp table with data from the csv but didn't find the right format to make it work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `User::Horodatage` variable values are along the following format:

```
2023/06/09 3:24:52 PM GMT+1
```

Step #1: Use the following SSIS expression

```
REPLACE( REPLACE( @[User::Horodatage], "/", "-"),"GMT+1","") + "+01:00"
```

It will output the following value:

```
2023-06-09 3:24:52 PM +01:00
```

Step #2: Keep the Derived Column Task output data type as `DT_WSTR`.

If your target column data type is DATETIMEOFFSET(3), upon insert it will be the following value in the database:

```
2023-06-09 15:24:52.000 +01:00
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an additional reproducible test.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (dt DATETIMEOFFSET(3));
DECLARE @dt VARCHAR(30) = '2023-06-09 3:24:52 PM +01:00';

INSERT @tbl (dt)
SELECT @dt;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| dt |
| --- |
| 2023-06-09 15:24:52.000 +01:00 |

Comment: I have try your solution but it didn't work for me it gives me the same error code

Comment: Before I posted the answer, I tested it in SSIS. (1) Are you getting the same results after Step #1? (2) Did you keep the Derived Column Task output data type as DT_WSTR? (3) Does your target table column has `DATETIMEOFFSET(3)` data type?

Comment: yeah I have the data type DATETIMEOFFSET(3) and I used the expression `REPLACE(REPLACE(Horodatage,"/","-"),"GMT+1","") + "+01:00"`  and now I have new error message on ssis that says  ---
>[Destination DB [12]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

Comment: That "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" driver is deprecated. You need to use Microsoft OLEDB Driver **v.18.6.6**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-releases It is for SQL Server 2019 and earlier.

Comment: Also, what is your SQL Server version? (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)

Comment: this is my SQL server version 
`Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021125) - 15.0.2101.7 (X64)   Jan 23 2023 13:08:05   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: )`

Comment: Alas, you are not even on CU1. It is highly recommended to install latest SQL Server 2019 CU: https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/ and start using Microsoft OLEDB Driver v.18.6.6.

Comment: thank you for the advice sir, but i started with this version so can you help me on what can I do with my current SQL server version ??

Comment: Unfortunately, it is unusable SQL Server 2019 version. You must upgrade it with the latest CU. IMHO, that's the reason why you are getting the 0x80004005. error.

Comment: i have updated the sql server version to the last CU `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU22) (KB5027702) - 15.0.4322.2 (X64)   Jul 27 2023 18:11:00   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: ) ` But i still recive the same error code `[Destination DB [12]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
`

Comment: You missed one of my comments above: *"That "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" driver is deprecated. You need to use Microsoft OLEDB Driver v.18.6.6:..."*

Comment: I do used the _Microsoft OLEDB Driver v.18.6.6_

Comment: thank u for your help it work, i have added Data Conversion component and convert the data type to dbtimestapoffset and it works